# Error with syscall 318 for gem5, when executing with a multi agent reinforcement learning algorithm

Tags: python, c, x86-64, system-calls, gem5

I'm trying to execute a python algorithm (*https://github.com/shariqiqbal2810/maddpg-pytorch*) on gem5 in se mode in X86. But, at first I got an  *error syscall 318 out of range*.
So, I tried to import the get random function into the syscalltlb64 source code, like this:

```
{ 313, "finit_module" },
{ 314, "sched_setattr" },
{ 315, "sched_getattr" },
{ 316, "renameat2" },
{ 317, "seccomp" },
{ 318, "getrandom"},
{ 319, "memfd_create" },
{ 320, "kexec_file_load" },
{ 321, "bpf" },
```

Again, I got an error saying syscall 318 unimplemented. So, I just did:

```
  { 318, "getrandom", getrandomFunc},
```

Agin, the problem continues as I got an error saying:

```
    {318, "getrandom", <expression error>}, {319, "memfd_create"}, {320, "kexec_file_load"}, {321, "bpf"}}' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'gem5::SyscallDescTable<gem5::X86ISA::EmuLinux::SyscallABI64>'
  374 | };
      | ^
      | |
      | <brace-enclosed initializer list>
scons: *** [build/X86/arch/x86/linux/syscall_tbl64.o] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
*** Summary of Warnings ***
```

Can anyone help me how to solve this problem?
Note: My linux kernel version is 5.4.0-88-generic and I'm using ubuntu 20.04 LTS.
Thanks for the help